# Encrypt mails - No Provider configured for S/MIME

Tags: android, encryption, jakarta-mail, smime

From this codesnippet:

```
try {
    EncryptionUtils smimeUtils = EncryptionManager.getEncryptionUtils(EncryptionManager.SMIME);
    char[] smimePw = new String("hello world").toCharArray();
    EncryptionKeyManager smimeKeyMgr = smimeUtils.createKeyManager();
    smimeKeyMgr.loadPrivateKeystore(privateKeyStore, smimePw);

   } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
            Log.e("NoSuchProvider: ", e.getMessage());
   } catch (CertificateException e) {
            Log.e("Certificate: ", e.getMessage());
   } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            Log.e("KeyStore: ", e.getMessage()); 
   } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            Log.e("No Such Algorithm: ", e.getMessage()); 
   } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("IO: ", e.getMessage());
   }
```

I try to load the `S/MIME` encryption manager, but this code throws an `NoSuchProviderException` telling me this:

```
No provider configured for S/MIME
```

I'm following [this](http://javamail-crypto.sourceforge.net/) guide, which is telling me to add the following `.jar-files`:

1. javamail-crypto.jar
2. bcprov-jdk14-122.jar
3. bcmail-jdk14-122.jar

I couldn't find the extact version with the ending `-122` but I included the following `jar-files` to my build path:

1. bcprov-jdk14-147
2. bcmail-jdk14-147
3. javamail-crypto
4. javamail-crypto-bouncycastle-smime

But it still throws the `exception`, could anybody give me a hint on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Probably you still have to initiate and add the provider, not just add the .jar files to the runtime.

Comment: I'm doing as you say, this way: `Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());` this line of code is added to the constructor.

Comment: That should be the general idea, as long as the BC provider is the one required for the `EncryptionManager`. I'm not so sure about the last part. Maybe you need to add another provider - from the package containing `EncryptionManager`?

Comment: Ran into the same issue, with newer jdk.  I think the underlying problem is that the META-INF/javamail-crypto.providers file (found in javamail-crypto-bouncycastle-smime) is not readable somehow.  This is the file that contains the provider definition/mapping for S/MIME.  Still couldn't figure out how to get it working, though.